# Ugly URLs when there's pagination

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

My Permanent Link Setting:
**/%category%/%post_id%.html**

When there's pagination, the Url looks like this:
**www.example.com/%category%/%post_id%.html/2**
But I want this:
**www.example.com/%category%/%post_id%-2.html**
Plz tell me how to do (with Functions.php?)

Comment: Why do you have an extension in your URLs? And I think what you're seeing is correct. Having a `-2` in your URLs means you need it in your post titles. However you can overwrite the URL using URL rewriting.

Comment: What I meant is change %post_id%.html/[page] into this→%post_id%-[page].html

Comment: Aha, then you will have to rewrite the URL. Read upon it, it's a very vast topic. I think in your case it should be simple. I think a digit in the title should already be allowed so you wont need to define this URL pattern in .HTACCESS. You'll have to add a rule that checks if you're on a pagination page and adds the page number to the title.